# bootstrap 4 - navbar brand logo not change in scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I added  bootstrap 4 and I created the navbar, it is working good, but i have some conflict I tried to change when the scroll down change the navbar logo, but its not working correctly, anyone know how to fix that issue.

This is my code:

```css
$(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
                    $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/808080?Text=newLogo');
                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000) {
                    $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=oldLogo');
                }
            })
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<header class="main_menu home_menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" > <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=oldLogo" style="width:50px;">   </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button></nav>
      </div></div></div></header>
      
      <section>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
  <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>  <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>  <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
  <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
  <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
  <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
      </section>
```

Comment: What is not working. It looks like it is updating the image.

Comment: @MayankPatel , Hi, look my sample .  when i scroll down navbar logo  not changed

Comment: Check my fiddle in the answer. It is working fine.

Comment: I have fixed navbar for testing. Let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: @MayankPatel hi, I mean like this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyskkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out below fiddle. It is working fine. It is just that your image is getting hidden under scroll otherwise your image is getting changed.

Please note, for illustration purposes, I have fixed your `navbar` header.

Just use `navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top` classes for your navbar and it should work as expected.

```js
$(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
                    $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/808080?Text=newLogo');
                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000) {
                    $('.navbar .navbar-brand img').attr('src','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=oldLogo');
                }
            })
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<header class="main_menu home_menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" > <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?Text=oldLogo" style="width:50px;">   </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button></nav>
      </div></div></div></header>
      
      <section>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
         <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
         <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
         <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
         <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
         <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
         <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
        <div>Placeholder</div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for your solution, but i mean like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyskkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I updated my answer. You can achieve by changing a few classes (navbar classes) in your code.

Comment: Hello there, Thanks for your valuable time and solution , it's worked for me